# Convergence in Probability (Analytical Solution Verification)

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, convergence, uniform-distribution

**Problem**: Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ be independent random variables that are uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$. Show that the sequence $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots$ converges in probability to some limit, and identify the limit for

\begin{equation*}
Y_n=\dfrac{X_n}{n}
\end{equation*}

**My-Solution I**: $X_n \sim \text{Uni}[-1,1]$

[image]

**Conjecture**: As $n \longrightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{X_n}{n} \longrightarrow 0$ therefore $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

---

***Definition* Convergence in Probability**:
Let $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots$ be a sequence of random variables (not necessarily independent), and let $a$ be a real number. We say that the sequence of $Y_n$ **converges to $a$ in probability**, if for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}  \mathbb{P}(|Y_n - a|) \geq \epsilon)=0
\end{equation*}

---

In our case $a=0$ and for $\epsilon >0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n - 0|) \geq \epsilon)$

Using derived distributions

\begin{align*}
F_{Y_n}(y_n)&=\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq y_n)\\
            &=\mathbb{P}\bigg(\frac{X_n}{n} \leq y_n\bigg)=\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq ny_n)\\
            &= \frac{ny_n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

differentiating with respect to $y_n$, we get

\begin{equation*}
    f_{Y_n}(y_n)=
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{n}{2}, & \  \text{if}\quad y_n \in [-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]\\
      0, & \ \text{otherwise} \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

[image]

From the PDF of $Y_n$ it is clear when $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|Y_n-0| \geq \epsilon)&=\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon) \\
                                 &= \mathbb{P}(Y_n \geq \epsilon)+\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq -\epsilon)\\
                                 &= 0+0=0
\end{align*}

for all $n$ with $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$, so $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon) \longrightarrow 0$. Hence $Y_n$ converges to zero as per definition.

**Solution II**:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|Y_n-0| \geq \epsilon) &= \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon)\\
                                  &= \mathbb{P}\bigg(\Bigg\vert\frac{X_n}{n}\Bigg\vert \geq \epsilon\bigg)\\
                                  &= \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq n\epsilon)\\
                                  &= \mathbb{P}(X_n \geq n\epsilon)+\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq -n\epsilon)\\
                                  &= 0+0=0 \quad \text{as}\: \epsilon > 0 \:\text{with}\: n \rightarrow \infty
\end{align*}
So $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon) \longrightarrow 0$ with $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

**Manual Solution:** For any $\epsilon > 0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon) = 0,
\end{equation*}
for all $n$ with $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$, so $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon) \longrightarrow 0$.

Does my solutions make sense or not. Kindly validate the solutions.